# How do I make call to JSON Data Asynchronous to stop User interface from freezing in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, asynchronous

I wrote some code to get some data from a web service and load the data in a UITableView on the screen of my iOS objective-c app. I discovered that the UI freezes when I launch the app, and I'm sure it's because of call to web service JSON data in the viewDidload that's causing it. how do i make the process asynchronous? This is my code

```
// Calling the web service
NSURL *liveTunesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.radiome.org/tunes/realliveTunes"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:liveTunesURL];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
self.liveTunes = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *liveTunesArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Data"];

for (NSDictionary *liveTunesDictionary in liveTunesArray) {
    LiveTunes *liveTune = [LiveTunes liveTunesWithChannel:[liveTunesDictionary objectForKey:@"channel"]];
    liveTune.id = [liveTunesDictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
    liveTune.channel = [liveTunesDictionary objectForKey:@"channel"];
    liveTune.description = [liveTunesDictionary objectForKey:@"description"];
    liveTune.urlPrefix = [liveTunesDictionary objectForKey:@"urlPrefix"];
    liveTune.filename = [liveTunesDictionary objectForKey:@"filename"];
    liveTune.url = [liveTunesDictionary objectForKey:@"url"];
    liveTune.audio_stream = [liveTunesDictionary objectForKey:@"audio_stream"];
    [self.liveTunes addObject:liveTune];
}
```

and here is part of my tableView data source code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
LiveTunes *liveTune = [self.liveTunes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([liveTune.url isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:liveTune.thumbnailURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    cell.imageView.image = image;
}
else {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"music_cell.png"];
}

cell.textLabel.text = liveTune.channel;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = liveTune.description;

return cell;
```

}

Can someone help me out to make the process Asynchronous so that the UI stops freezing.

Comment: You can use GCD or `NSURLConnection`'s asynchronous method. However I recommend to use `AFNetworking`. It is easier and safer.

Comment: I strongly recommend you use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: You can also use `NSURLSession` if you're targeting iOS8 and above. It doesn't need 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Look in to using NSMutableURLRequest. Once you have a request object, use it like so.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *af = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [af setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //Success
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //Failure
        UIAlertController *confirmDialog =
        [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Request Failed - Status %ld (%@)", (long)[operation.response statusCode], error.description]
                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [confirmDialog addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:nil]];
        [self presentViewController:confirmDialog animated:true completion:nil];
    }];

    [af start];
```